# GeoServer:Column 40 is out of range, min: 41 max:44

Tags: geoserver

I have configured Layer with GeoWebcache on GeoServer2.13 while making the request from Openlayer
Url:

> https://geoserver.althing.io/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?layer=Public_Geo%3APumpJack&style=&tilematrixset=EPSG%3A4326&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix=EPSG%3A4326%3A7&TileCol=40&TileRow=39

I'm getting the following Response Exception:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExceptionReport version="1.1.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://geowebcache.org/schema/ows/1.1.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
  <Exception exceptionCode="TileOutOfRange" locator="TILECOLUMN">
    <ExceptionText>Column 40 is out of range, min: 41 max:44</ExceptionText>
  </Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

Any help to resolved this Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve this only by not requesting tiles that are outside the matrix provided, in this case between 41 and 44.

It simply means that your client is trying to draw a map that is to the left of your map and in most cases you can simply ignore it. If it worries you then you should switch to a smarter client that takes the range of tiles available into account before it makes requests.